# Actions not appearing on timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

I have seen similar questions here, but none of the answers seem to work in my case.

The case is REALLY simple. I "publish" an "article" - this action is sent to fb (using PHP) (using publish_actions scope). All the calls seem fine. All set-up on FB seems ok - the objects and actions are standard. I am the admin etc.

On Facebook - I can see the action in the activity log. If I click on the timestamp in the activity log I can see the whole post, including the og:description etc. AFAICT this is what should also appear on the timeline.

But it's not showing!?

One thing to note is in the activity log on the right hand side of the new entry for my action, the status is always "allowed on timeline". But even if I change the status to "shown on timeline", it is still not shown on the timeline.

It must be something very simple. Facebook has the content (not a scraping error), has registered the activity but just does not show the object in the timeline.

I also tested using the graph API explorer I get the same result, i.e. entry in activity log but not in timeline etc. I get an objectid returned - as expected.

JUST to add: What I DO see (as the User) on the timeline is an "Activity" box at the top right hand side.

Comment: You really need to explain and ask some questions here.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh Something not clear? Please elucidate.

Comment: The api call to post the "publish" of the "article" returns an Object Graph Action Id.
I can enter this Id into the debugger
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/action?q=<THE Id NUMBER> and get exactly what's expected:
`News Feed Story`
``
`James Cook published an article on <App Name>.`
`The Headline`
`The Text of the og:description shown here ..`
``

But STILL nothing showing in the timeline OR in the News Feed!

Comment: Update after 1 week:
1. created new app went through the recipe_box example on facebook - got it to work. By which I mean I had entries in the Activity Log which when clicked "shown on timeline" DID show up on the timeline
2. The moved back to php - that worked too.

So I'm not exactly sure WHY the first example didn't work BUT here are some observations.
1. If the post is missing an image (or otherwise not complete?) it is not posted on the timeline.
2. Initial issue - not 100% clear. Could have have something to do with the wrong access token or other permission incorrect.

Comment: In fact moving back to PHP : The entries showed up directly in the timeline - without the need to click them in the Activity Log (see above)